# Output for finding kth digit from right of a^b does not come as Expected?

Tags: java

> Given two numbers a and b, find kth digit from right of a^b?

Link for the problem:

http://www.practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problem-page.php?pid=302

MyApproach:

I took 4 numbers as Input.First was the number of test cases.Then,Input was numbers a b and k respectively(Seperated by space).I calculated a^b and then from right searched each number till the time kth digit is not equal to the count.If I get them equal I returned the remainder expected.

Below is the Code:

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
       Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
          int T=sc.nextInt();

          for(int i=1;i<=T;i++)
          { 
              int count=1;
              int a=sc.nextInt();
              System.out.print(" ");
              int b=sc.nextInt();
               System.out.print(" ");
              int k=sc.nextInt();
              long result=(long) Math.pow(a,b);
              if(k!=count)
              {
                  while(k!=count)
                  {
                      count++;
                      int remainder=(int) (result%10);
                      result=result/10;

                  }
              }
              result=result%10;
              System.out.println(result);
          }
    }


GeeksId Output:                  

Wrong !! Here your code Failed 

Input: 

7 6 3 

And its Correct output is: 

6
```

Eclipse ID:

Input:

7 6 3

Output

6

> Wny I am getting Failed on geeksId?Is my solution do not produce correct output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can also be done this way without much String operations and not expecting the intermediate output a^b to store in long data type,

```
private void handle() {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int T = scanner.nextInt();
    for(int i = 0; i < T; i++) {
        findKthDigit(scanner);
    }
    scanner.close();
}

private void findKthDigit(Scanner scanner) {
    int a = scanner.nextInt();
    int b = scanner.nextInt();
    int k = scanner.nextInt();
    System.out.println((int)((Math.pow(a, b) % Math.pow(10, k))
            / Math.pow(10, k-1)));
}
```

As requested, your program is modified to make it work in GFG system,

```
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
      Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
      int T=sc.nextInt();

      for(int i=1;i<=T;i++)
      { 
          int count=1;
          int a=sc.nextInt();
          //System.out.print(" ");
          int b=sc.nextInt();
          // System.out.print(" ");
          int k=sc.nextInt();
          long result=(long) Math.pow(a,b);
          if(k!=count)
          {
              while(k!=count)
              {
                  count++;
                  int remainder=(int) (result%10);
                  result=result/10;

              }
          }
          result=result%10;
          System.out.println(result);
      }
}
```

Hope this helps to understand. (however, you need to check other related exceptions for a good programming practice)

Comment: @Jason arora your program is correct, but your output line prepends with two white-spaces, where the GeeksforGeeks system expects an single Integer as output, hence your program failed as per the system.
Solution:
comment two lines,
`// System.out.print(" ");
...
// System.out.print(" ");`

and the GFG system will make it pass.

Comment: Yes you pointed it right.Can you edit the code my codeWhat you are trying to say?Where I need to comment.

Comment: Thanku.From your code i have understood that GFG System inserts automatically those blank spaces in the line where the input is T,a,b where T is the number of testcases.a is the first number and b is the second number.

Comment: How you came with the logic of "(int)((Math.pow(a, b) % Math.pow(10, k)) / Math.pow(10, k-1)".I also have dry run it it is producing correct output. Can you tell me your thought process it will be very helpful.

Comment: Since this question is about number manipulation, this can be done in several ways.
I saw the GFG question link that you shared, in that there's a tag mentioned as [maths], so it can be solved with simple mathematical equation. And any digit (kth) can be retrieved with basic mod and division of 10^x. 

Hence ((a^b)%(10^k))/(10^(k-1)).

Comment: That's great mathematics.You generalised the thing after looking at the pattern.Good work.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you did not follow the direction of the problem. The problem gives you a few constraints. you do not do a check for those. You should add the code to check that, so it will make sure you do not run into any exceptions.

I wanted to point out that you can just convert the `Math.pow(a,b)` result to string, and print the `length - k` char using the charAt function. This will make it very easy. and gets rid of the loops.

Code for that part is:

```
String tempString = String.valueOf(result);
System.out.println(tempString.charAt(tempString.length() - k));
```

Hope this puts you in the right direction.

Comment: Constraints for 7^6=?It doesn't cross any constraint.What exception it produced

Comment: well the constraint to check the following:
`1<=T<=100`
`1<=a , b <=15`
`1<=k<=|totaldigits in a^b|`

You should always do the input validation asked by program. What you have would work, but it is not correct since someone can enter -4 for the b, and that will mess up your `math.pow(a,b)`

Comment: Yes you are right I will keep in mind the cases.Thank you.Except for this thing I think the way I am producing output is different from the Output Expected.Can you guide me what changes to be made

Comment: @Jasonarora, Remove the two `system.out.print(" ");` lines that you have. That should resolve the issue. Your code is right, but the output is not consistent. If this solves your issue, please up vote/mark correct. If you need further assistance I would be happy to help. Thank you :)